# Close tab command in Ubuntu 20.04.01, GNOME 3.36.8

Tags: 20.04

After I upgraded my system from Ubuntu 16.04 LTS first to 18.04 then to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, ctrl+w stopped working (both in different browsers and commandline)! I have tried looking for the command in keyboard shortcuts, but there is no "close tab". I also tried adding new "close tab" shortcut, but I'm not sure what command to use for closing a tab!
Can someone help me set up close current tab? I'm going crazy not being able to close tabs!

Comment: Strange, because these keys are controlled by the applications themselves (i.e., these are not systemwide shortcut keys). Temporarily create a new account and see if the issue persists there. If not, you know the problem is with your user configuration. If yes, then it is a systemwide issue. Then consider a fresh install, wiping the previous installation. With upgrading, there is always a chance of issues.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. In the new account close tab works! I have tried to reset keyboard shortcuts, but the problem persists! Do you have any other suggestions for finding which user config is causing this?

Comment: Not right now. That means you can probably do without a reinstall, but you will have to reset your account if you do not find the specific configuration setting.

Comment: Reseting my account settings worked! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer in comments, so I thought I should put it here as well. I was able to reset my account settings by the following command and it fixed my issue.

```
dconf reset -f /
```